# Angular mat-table display dynamic key value pair in each row

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a key value pair data as follows in JSON format. Keys will be dynamic in nature. There is no specific set of keys that will be part of the JSON. I want to show them in a tabular format using Angular `mat-table`.

```
var data = {
 "cars" : 24,
 "fruit" : "apple",
 "phone" : "Iphone",
 "food" : "Burger"
};
```

My table output should be:

- table header should contain 2 columns KEY and VALUE
- each row data should be above dynamic json key value.

Expected table output:

[image: Expected table output:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is no need to transform the object into an array.
You can easily use `keyvalue` pipe.

In the ts file:

```
// properties of the class
displayedColumns: string[] = ['key', 'value'];
dataSource = data;

// use this method if you want to keep the order of the object properties
public orderByKey(a, b) {
    return a.key;
  }
```

In the html file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource | keyvalue:orderByKey" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

You can check how it works in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbxyjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: I have to sort the values by Key and Value. How do I use matSort in this case?

Comment: If I'll have some free time later, I'll try to find a solution for this case but for sorting or filtering, you should probably transform the object into an array. Your life will be easier.

Comment: I was looking for something similar and ended up converting the data, but can we also do it using p-table?I have array of key-value pairs as my data

Answer (score 2):

Transform your object into array

```
  dataSource = [];
  var data = {
    cars: 24,
    fruit: "apple",
    phone: "Iphone",
    food: "Burger"
  };

  for (const key in data) {
    dataSource.push({ key, value: data[key] });
  }
```

and to use it in angular material

.ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
export interface RowElement {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: "table-basic-example",
  styleUrls: ["table-basic-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "table-basic-example.html"
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  data = {
    cars: 24,
    fruit: "apple",
    phone: "Iphone",
    food: "Burger"
  };

  displayedColumns: string[] = ["key", "value"];
  dataSource: RowElement[];

  constructor() {
    for (const key in this.data) {
      this.dataSource.push({ key, value: this.data[key] });
    }
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <!-- Key Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Key</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.key}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Value Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.value}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you has a typo error, is `{key:key:value:this.data[key]}`. you can also use map, not a for  `dataSource = Object.keys(this.data).map(key=>({key:key,value:this.data[key]}))`

Comment: @Eliseo that's not typo error, that is `Object Property Value Shorthand in JavaScript with ES6`

Comment: @Eliseo `for .. in ` does that without need to call additional method like `Object.keys` and `map` function

Comment: @AhmedKesha Thanks for the quick reply. I tried the solution but I am getting ERROR
Error: Could not find column with id "key". Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-ex Can you have a look once?

Comment: @vamsi I updated my answer you just to modify `matColumnDef="key"` and ,matColumnDef="value"

Comment: @vamsi here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-ex-zwa6cf